# how to know input position with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this validation plugin http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/ and i wondered, how can you determinate the position of the input? With that plugin as you could notice, display a message but how does it knows exactly where the input with a error is and put the message exactly there?

Answer (score 2):

The source code for this plugin, specifically the one for the error message container looks like this:

```
createErrorContainer: function(form, el) {      
  if(typeof form == 'function') {
    this.defaults.createErrorContainer = form;
    return this;
  } else {
    var elOffset = el.offset();

    return $('<div/>', {
             html   : '<ul></ul><span></span>',
             'class': 'ketchup-error',
             css    : {
                        top : elOffset.top,
                        left: elOffset.left + el.outerWidth() - 20
                      }
           }).appendTo('body');
  }
},
```

So as you can see, it's using the .offset() method to fetch the position of the input fields in relation to the document.

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 1):

After you get the element (possibly by id), in raw JavaScript:

```
element.offsetLeft
element.offsetTop
```

Or with jQuery's cross-browser [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function.

For validation Html5 does this already. You don't really need to do validation with Javascript. There are also [pollyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) available that fill in support for html5 form validation when a browser doesn't support it.